# Computing variance of sum

Tags: statistics, signal-processing

I want to find an expression for the variance of $\hat{b}=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t} y_t u_t}{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2}$ where $u_t$ is the deterministic input signal of the process $y_t=bu_t+e_t$ and $e_t$ is white Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma_e^2$. Also $\lambda$ is a constant value.

Im stuck since I dont know how to handle the summations when dealing with variance

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to clarify first is the following. Are $y_t=bu_t+e_t$ with $t=1,2,...,N$ uncorrelated? If it's the case you should know the general equation for sum of random variable [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdZ04.png). You only need to work with the upper term.

Comment: It's not mentioned that they are uncorrelated, so I would assume no but not really sure

Comment: Could you help me out? Why is it enough to only work with the upper term, I dont understand?

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to work only with the upper term in terms of variance because the lower one is deterministic. It's a number (depends on t but still a number at the end). The upper term is the only one that has a random variable, $y_t$. Is it clear?
Regarding variables correlation, you can procede without assuming uncorrelation until you need the covariance that I showed you in the picture, then make a comment if you assume that they are uncorrelated.

Comment: So you are saying that $V\left[ \frac{\sum_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t} y_t u_t}{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2} \right]=\frac{V\left[\sum_{t=1}^N\lambda^{N-t} y_t u_t\right]}{\sum_{t=1}^{N}\lambda^{N-t}u_t^2} $ ?

Comment: Almost. Since lower term is a number that only depends on time, you can name it $b(t)$, so remember that constants get out squared from variance operator. $V(\frac{X}{b(t)})=\frac{1}{b^2(t)}V(X)$.